# Spectrum of cocktail party graph?

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Does anyone know if there is a reference for the spectrum of the cocktail party graph? How can I find the eigenvalues of this famous graph?

Comment: FYI, the spectrum of the cocktail party graph is well-known especially because of a theorem of Alan Jerome Hoffman and Dwijendra Kumar Ray-Chaudhuri, according to which the only regular connected graphs with least eigenvalue $\geq-2$ are line graphs and the cocktail party graphs (and a finite number of sporadic exceptions each of which has at most 16 vertices). Roughly, cocktail party graphs have exceptionally large least eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2):

For any $k\in\omega$, the spectrum of the hyperoctahedral graph (aka cocktail party) graph on $n=2k$ vertices is known to be

> $(2k-2)^{\times 1},0^{\times k},(-2)^{\times(k-1)}$.

(Here, ${}^\times$ means repeated juxtaposition, not multiplication.)

A reference is [J. L. Gross, J. Yellen, *Handbook of Graph Theory*, CRC Press, 2004, ISBN 9780203490204, page 559].

One should also note that since each cocktail party graph is (vertex-degree-) regular, there is a useful connection of its spectrum to the spectrum of its *complement*, and this complement is a *perfect matching*, whose spectrum is particularly easy to understand.